# WPF Image Gallery

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, gallery

I'm going to be driving a touch-screen application (not a web app) that needs to present groups of images to users.  The desire is to present a 3x3 grid of images with a page forward/backward capability.  They can select a few and I'll present just those images.

I don't see that `ListView` does quite what I want (although WPF is big enough that I might well have missed something obvious!).  I could set up a `Grid` and stuff images in the grid positions.  But I was hoping for something nicer, more automated, less brute-force.  Any thoughts or pointers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to use an `ItemsControl`/`ListBox` and then set a `UniformGrid` panel for a 3x3 display as its `ItemsPanel` to achieve a proper WPF bindable solution.

```
 <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3"/>
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  <Image Source="Images\img1.jpg" Width="100"/>
  <Image Source="Images\img2.jpg" Width="50"/>
  <Image Source="Images\img3.jpg" Width="200"/>
  <Image Source="Images\img4.jpg" Width="75"/>
  <Image Source="Images\img5.jpg" Width="125"/>
  <Image Source="Images\img6.jpg" Width="100"/>
  <Image Source="Images\img7.jpg" Width="50"/>
  <Image Source="Images\img8.jpg" Width="50"/>
  <Image Source="Images\img9.jpg" Width="50"/>
 </ListBox>
```

You need to set your collection of Images as ItemsSource binding if you are looking for a dynamic solution here. But the question is too broad to give an exact answer.

Answer (score 10):

I know that this is a pretty old question, but I'm answering because this page is in the first page on Google and this link could be useful for someone.

[WPF Photo Viewer Demo](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/Sample%20Applications/PhotoViewerDemo)

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You can use simple `ListBox` control and customize its `ItemsPanel` template and add `WrapPanel` in it.  `WrapPanel` puts items in a Horizontal Tiling layout, where you can set its max width to incorporate 3 items in one row and it will create more rows for 3 items till last one fills.